# How to use imbinarize function in matlab correctly when the input is a 3D data

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to use Otsu's thresholding method on my 3D matrix by using "imbinarize" function on Matlab. There are no error warnings, but the result is incorrect.
If I compare the original 3D matrix to the thresholded model, the thresholded model looks very bad.

This is the code that I ran on Matlab:

```
T2=graythresh (data);
BW2=imbinarize(data,T2);
BW2=single(BW2);
figure ();
volshow(BW2);
figure ();
volshow(data);
```

After imbinarize my single data turns into a logical data, so I added BW2=single(BW2) for consistency. I feel like the issue is caused by turning the single data to logical data.
Before and after adding this line.

[image]
[image]

Here are my results. The left model is the thresholded result and the right model is the original one.
[image]

After comment of Alamakanambra I changed normalized my input before using imbinarize, which led to a better result, but the visualization of the data is still different (e.g. texture).
[image]

I don't understand why my output is worse than my input. What have I done wrong?

Comment: In RGB image usually image is converted to grayscale by weighted average of 3 channels and then threshold is applied. If you have n channel data, then you can threshold each channel separately or average all the channels and apply threshold.

Comment: @user8190410 it's a one channel data, type single, so I think there is a different issue, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: `imbinarize` uses a 256-bin image histogram to compute Otsu's threshold as mentioned in documentation. if your data has some other histogram, you can use `otsuthresh` function.

Comment: @user8190410 Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, but sadly I got the same result

Comment: @Luna can you please provide the 3D matrix in your question to form the [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Bilal Hi i edited my question, hopefully it's more clear now

Comment: @Luna still the input (3D matrix) is not available to replicate your issue!

Comment: @Bilal Sorry I'm not allowed to share the original data.

Comment: @Luna are your data in [0,1] range? because that's what imbinarize expects.

Comment: @Alamakanambra No, I didn't. I just normalized it and the results look still a bit weird but a lot better. Thanks!

Comment: @Alamakanambra I added a picture of the new output after normalizing my data

Comment: @Luna Now, check the plotted data (`BW2` I guess): `hist(BW2(:))`, there should be just 2 cols (0s and 1s).

Comment: @Alamakanambra yes that is true